# Webpack - React, How to pass data from script tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have embeddable react widget with webpack config, below is the script tag which will be embedded in the client side.

```
<script>
    (function (w, d, s, o, f, js, fjs) {
        w['simple-widget'] = o; w[o] = w[o] || function () { (w[o].q = w[o].q || []).push(arguments) };
        js = d.createElement(s), fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        js.id = o; js.src = f; js.async = 1; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(window, document, 'script', 'w1', 'widget.js'));
    w1('init', { targetElementId: 'simple-widget', message: "some string" });

</script>
```

How to capture

```
message: "some string"
```

and send it to react ?

Below is my code to apiHandle

```
function apiHandler(api, params) {
    if (!api) throw Error("API method required");
    api = api.toLowerCase();

    let config = window[widgetConfigName];

    switch (api) {
        case "init":
            config = Object.assign({}, config, params);
            window[widgetConfigName] = config;

             // get a reference to the created widget component so we can
            // call methods as needed
            widgetComponent = React.createRef();
            ReactDOM.render(
           <Widget ref={widgetComponent} />,
               document.getElementById(config.targetElementId)
           );
       break;
      case "message":
          console.log("switch case message");
          // Send the message to the current widget instance
          widgetComponent.current.setMessage(params);
          break;
      default:
          throw Error(`Method ${api} is not supported`);
    }
}
```

Below is my react Wideget.js Component

```
class Widget extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
         this.state = {
            message: null,
        };
    }

render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
        <div className="main_container">
            {message}
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `message` property from the `simple-widget` element if it exists in your DOM elements.

```
class Widget extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      message: null,
    };
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    const widgetElement = document.getElementById('simple-widget');
    this.setState({message: widgetEelement.message})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main_container">
        {message}
      </div>
   );
  }
}
```

##### Explanation

In the component did mount function, you can get the widget by its **id** and get the `message` property from it, then set this message to the state.